# show a message to everyone who is not using chrome with Angular 2

Tags: angular, browser-detection

I have a situation where I need to display a warning message to everyone who is not using chrome. I tried this with vanilla JS but ran into issues and wondered if in fact I could achieve this with Angular 2 and just set it on my root component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [ng2-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-responsive).

You can show/hide component (for eg. your message component) based on browser type, device type, viewport size and orientation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with the added benefit it's easy to allow access to other browsers as we update for them.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the browser is chrome in the onInit() method of your root component and show toaster using primeNG.

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title:string;
  message:string;
  msgs: Message[] = [];
  constructor(private _window:WindowRef) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.title = 'Check browser example'
    let isChrome = !!this._window.nativeWindow.chrome && !!this._window.nativeWindow.chrome.webstore;
    if(!isChrome){
      this.message = "You are not using Chrome";
      this.msgs.push({severity:'warn', summary:'Warning Message', detail:'Your are not using Chrome'});
      alert("Not using chrome");
    }else{
      this.msgs.push({severity:'success', summary:'Success Message', detail:'Your are using Chrome'});
      this.message = "You are using Chrome";
    }
  }
}
```

To get the reference to the window object create a service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
    // return the native window obj
    return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {

    get nativeWindow(): any {
        return _window();
    }

}
```

**Edit: ** Replaced plunkr with primeNG Example and created service to get reference of window object.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/pTgV3p7MpKfDb5irlaQn?p=preview

Reference: [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: I get the following error: ```Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window'.```

Comment: ```let isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    if(!isChrome){
      this.unsafeBrowser = true;
    }else{
      this.unsafeBrowser = false;
    }```

Comment: I got it in Chrome & Safari

Comment: I have updated my answer. It runs just fine on chrome for me. I'm on windows machine so can't give support on safari.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to detect browser in your Angular2 app, you can use only javascript in this way:

```
var isChromeBrowser = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
```

but I think that you would like detect Blink engine, not Chrome browser. Every detection code by javascript you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

You can use just *window* variable in TypeScript file, but if you are going create unit test, you should create some service to getting *window object*, for example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
  public window = window;
}
```

and use it in this way:

```
@Component({
     templateUrl:"someComponent.html"
})
export class SomeComponent {

  public isChromeBrowser: boolean;

  constructor(private windowService: WindowService) {
!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    this.isChromeBrowser = windowService.window.chrome && !!windowService.window.chrome.webstore;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement:

```
const isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
```

throws an error:

> Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window'

The fix is:

```
const isChrome = !!window['chrome'] && (!!window['chrome'].webstore || !!window['chrome'].runtime);
```

I have been testing it, and works fine:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const isChrome = !!window['chrome'] && (!!window['chrome'].webstore || !!window['chrome'].runtime);
    console.log( 'isChrome: ' + isChrome );
}
```